# Python error - TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()

Tags: python

I want to read the price from the below site.
But when I run, I got [TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()] error.

```
word = '0735850859699'
driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe')
url = driver.get("https://www.lotteon.com/p/product/LM" + str(word))
time.sleep(3)

soup = BeautifulSoup(url, 'lxml')
content = soup.findAll("div", {"class":"price"}).text
print(content)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vTyDy.png)

Comment: findAll returns a list which does not have a .text property.

Comment: Can you give us the full error text?

Comment: full error:                      
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\0_MINSU\PythonWorksapce\practice.py", line 165, in <module>
    soup = BeautifulSoup(url, 'lxml')
  File "C:\Users\lemi7005\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\bs4\__init__.py", line 310, in __init__
    elif len(markup) <= 256 and (
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()

Answer (score 0):

Your url object is a Nonetype from .get().  You want to use the method .page_source:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

word = '0735850859699'
firefoxoptions = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
firefoxoptions.set_headless()
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r"<gecko_driver_path_here>", 
                           firefox_options=firefoxoptions)
driver.get(f"https://www.lotteon.com/p/product/LM{word}")
url = driver.page_source

soup = BeautifulSoup(url, 'lxml')
content = soup.find("div", {"class":"price"}).text
print(content)
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, btw shall I use Firefox browser for this? Because I only have chrome browser in my laptop..!

Comment: Either will work just fine, I just happened to have Firefox.  Just be careful b/c the options setup is a little different with Chrome.